# jquery find() - how to exclude certain descendants, and their children?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have markup similar to this:

```
<div class='wrapper plugin'>
    //some content
    <div class='child-wrapper plugin'>
      //some more content
      <div>
        <ul>     
          <li><div class='cliky'>clicky!</div></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  <div class='cliky'>clicky!</div>
</div>
```

I need to be able to select the **first** `.clicky` div **only**, not any `.clicky` divs inside a  `.plugin > .plugin` div.

The wrapper has `.plugin` class too - might seem counter-intuitive so another way to view it is this: I want to get the `.clicky` children of a given `.plugin` div, but not `.plugin .plugin .clicky`.

I've tried selectors like:

`$('.wrapper').find('.clicky').not('.plugin > .clicky');`

But they still selected all child `.clicky` elements - including those of the nested `.plugin` element..

How would I be able to select only the `.plugin .clicky` elements of a particular `.plugin` div, but not any `.plugin .plugin .clicky` elements?

Comment: .wrapper is also having plugin class. that means no .clicky should be selected right?

Comment: I've read this question three times and I'm still not sure what you want.

Comment: No, sorry I know it's not all that clear - I need to select the first '.clicky' element inside a `.plugin` element, **excluding** any `.plugin .plugin .clicky`. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.wrapper .clicky').filter(function(){
   return $(this).parents('.plugin').length === 1
})
```

Comment: this is genius :) did the trick for me after a modification to deal with `n` levels of `.plugin` (bit of a mind bender lol)

Comment: .using `.closest()` would achieve the same thing, but be quicker as it would bail at the first encounter of '.plugin'.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.wrapper').find('.plugin .clicky')[0];
```

Should return the first element of the "found" array.If you need to incorporate the results in a jquery obj, just reaquire it.

```
var t = $( $('.wrapper').find('.plugin .clicky')[0]);
```

Comment: You should probably look at his markup again. I'm pretty sure children won't work here because wrapper's child is row, who's child is then cliky.

Comment: nope, sorry - children() will only get me a single level of descendants, as I said in the post it could be many levels below the wrapper. The important part is that I only select `.clicky` elements that are not children of `.plugin`, but **are** inside the wrapper.

Comment: @jammypeach Your wrapper itself has plugin class!

Comment: ha. i see the complication here. fiddle to come

Comment: This almost did the trick, the only reason I didn't mark as accepted is because it won't work if I use more than one `.clicky` element on the same level. +1 for good thinking though. I know my question wasn't easy to follow :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$('.wrapper .cliky').not('.plugin > .plugin .cliky');
```

or

```
$('.wrapper .cliky:not(.plugin > .plugin .cliky)');
```

Tested in jQuery 1.9